# Unclosed INDENT in line 6 ( CoffeeScript ) Compiler Error

Tags: javascript, mongodb, compiler-errors, coffeescript, database

Here is my code in CoffeeScript for a simple test with MongoDB.
When I run
  `coffee -c UserDataProvider.coffee`
I end up with an error UNCLOSED INDENT ON LINE 6

This is my code:

```
Db   = require('mongodb/db').Db
ObjectID = require('mongodb/bson/bson').ObjectID
Server   = require('mongodb/connection').Server

class UserDataProvider
    constructor = (host,port)->
        this.db = new Db( 'test' , new Server(host ,port,{}))

    getCollection = (callback) ->
        this.db.collection('data',(error,data)->
            if error then callback(error)
            else callback(data)
```

The StackTrace is:

```
Error: In UserDataProvider.coffee, unclosed INDENT on line 6
    at Error (unknown source)
    at Rewriter.ensureBalance (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/coffee-script/1.0.1/package/lib/rewriter.js:283:17)
    at Rewriter.rewrite (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/coffee-script/1.0.1/package/lib/rewriter.js:21:12)
    at Lexer.tokenize (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/coffee-script/1.0.1/package/lib/lexer.js:37:29)
    at Object.compile (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/coffee-script/1.0.1/package/lib/coffee-script.js:26:34)
    at /usr/local/lib/node/.npm/coffee-script/1.0.1/package/lib/command.js:117:33
    at /usr/local/lib/node/.npm/coffee-script/1.0.1/package/lib/command.js:85:26
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (fs.js:86:5)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:39:17)
    at afterRead (fs.js:843:12)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You should update your code to say `constructor:` and `getCollection:` rather than using `=`, in accordance with your other issue at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124383/another-coffeescript-error Just so other folks coming to this page won't get confused. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first left parenthesis on this line is never closed:

```
this.db.collection('data',(error,data) ->
```

It is actually not needed at all, so you probably want to remove it all together, if your intention is to pass "data" as the first argument and the `function(error, data) { ... }` as the second argument.

Comment: Awesome, didn't notice that. But now I end up getting a parse error for db.collection with unexpected '.'

Any ideas?

Comment: For this exact same code? it compiles fine for me when I remove the `(` from above. Just to make sure, I've changed the line from my answer to this: `this.db.collection 'data',(error,data) ->`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what happened but it works when I save and re-opened the file. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, the unhelpful error message is a bug in current version.

- https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1120